# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/<ipython-input-4-a6e9b589442e>'

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

when I use colaboratory to debug my code, I have Mounted Google cloud disk, this is my working dir: drive and sample_data this is my code:

```
def date():
    dir = '//Colab Notebooks//date'
```

But when I debug it, error:

```
FileNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-16-c7912b6365fb> in <module>()
71 algo=tpe.suggest,
72 max_evals=20,
73 trials=Trials()
74 )
75 
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/hyperas/optim.py in minimize(model, data, algo, max_evals, trials, functions, rseed, notebook_name, verbose, eval_space, return_space, keep_temp)
67 notebook_name=notebook_name,
68 verbose=verbose, --->
69 keep_temp=keep_temp)
70
71 best_model = None
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/hyperas/optim.py in base_minimizer(model, data, functions, algo, max_evals, trials, rseed, full_model_string, notebook_name, verbose, stack, keep_temp)
96 model_str = full_model_string
97 else: --->
98 model_str = get_hyperopt_model_string(model, data, functions, notebook_name, verbose, stack)
99 temp_file = './temp_model.py'
100 write_temp_files(model_str, temp_file)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/hyperas/optim.py in get_hyperopt_model_string(model, data, functions, notebook_name, verbose, stack)
183 else:
184 calling_script_file = os.path.abspath(inspect.stack()[stack][1]) -->
185 with open(calling_script_file, 'r') as f:
186 source = f.read()
187
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/<ipython-input-16-c7912b6365fb>'
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Could you post the full trace of the error? And please add how you mounted your notebook as well!

Comment: OK，thanks，原来还可以中文啊，i am in colaboratory to  mounte my notebook

Comment: 编辑器不让我贴图片，谢谢您啦，我觉得多交流我英语六级都可以过了

Comment: First of all, I can't speak Mandarin. Second of all, I believe your notebook is trying to access something and can't find it.. Could you add the code that caused the problem. All I see, is a function called `data` that hasn't bee called

Comment: Can I send it to your email,the code isn't fit for publicity .The code is used  for optimizing hyper parameter of cnn by hyperas.

Comment: no,  you don't have to ... just add the part where you mounted your notebook

Comment: OK,this is code                                                                                                                  def date():
    dir = '/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/date'                                                                        #to create train and valid date for training cnn model ,dir is a path including train date and valid date ,totally two folder

Comment: def mymodel(train_generator,valid_generator):                                                                     #creating cnn model,including hyper parameter

Comment: best_run = optim.minimize(model=mymodel,
              data=date,
              algo=tpe.suggest,)
              max_evals=20,
              trials=Trials()

Comment: print("Evalutation of best performing model:")
print(best_run)                                                                                                         
looking for best hyper parameter.

Comment: Are you loading a model from google drive??

Comment: YES,thanks，I am like to find the reason what caused this problem .when i debug the cnn model codes,path is not problem.the problem appears when I use "hyperas".so I think it may be the problem of hyperas setting.finally,thanks very much